# Ember Link To Next Object In Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aGUguJA/10

Using the bloggr example I built a list of posts and a post view and I've added 2 actions to the post template, Previous and Next.

```js
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   actions:{
        next: function(){
            //Go to next object in a model
          },
        prev: function(){
            //Go to previous object in a model
          }}
});
```

I can't figure out how to make the Previous and Next to work. I have a strong feeling I need to be using an ArrayController but I still wouldn't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to add two fields/variables in your post object i.e.

```
{
    id: '1',
    title: "Object 1",
    author: { name: "Awesome Person 1" },
    date: new Date('01-01-2013'),
    excerpt:"Lorem ..",
    body:"Lore.."
    next:2,
    prev:null

}
```

So you either have this information available in your data or create App.Post objects that get instanciated from the data and you write a simple iteration to populate the fields within the model part of your App.PostsRoute.
Then you can modify your template accordingly and pass the object or id from the link-to of next and previous buttons.

look at a working example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxajiVi/1/

**EDIT**
The following example demostrates the solution using Ember class and objects to create the linked list, no previous and next fields in json data and also works when visiting a post directly,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uWAmUba/1

Comment: Does this solution meet your needs?

Comment: It does meet the criteria, but copying the prev/next model into itself feels.. like overkill. For my latest attempt on next/prev <http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aGUguJA/18/> I'm doing a parseInt(this.get('id'),10)+1 and -1 respectively on the actions, but doing so I can't seem to get the model.length and id to disable them.

Comment: What you try to do can be fulfilled with a common data structure called doubly linked list (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) and that is what i described in my solution. So no overkill there. Although it could be designed a bit differently by introducing the prev and next fields in Ember objects instead of your json data. In that case when constructing the model, in the route, you could actually create Em objects from well defined Em classes (App.Post) that have the prev and next fields.

Comment: In addition your design should not include logic related to the whole set of posts within your single post controller. If your single post controller needs some information related to the whole set, then it should have an association (use ember needs property) to some other controller/manager that handles/manages the set i.e. App.PostsController. This results in higher cohesion of your controllers and separates their responsibilities. Some may argue that this kind of logic might need to be inside of routes, but this is a matter of preference i think when working with ember.

Comment: @ChrisScott incrementing/decrementing IDs to traverse your model is not correct,since it might break.Imagine that your ids may easily not be sequential, when the data comes from your datasource. Lastly,if you don't want to make a linked list structure with your objects then you could just get assistance from your posts controller by asking every time which object (post) is next/previous and whether the end/start of the list has been reached. However this may not be very efficient if you constantly navigate from these controls, due to the repeating calculations.

Comment: @ChrisScott please find here a modification of the solution you mentioned in your comments http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aGUguJA/19  with a slight influence of what i responded

Answer (score -2):

This could be helpful:

```
<button {{action "next"}}>Next</button>
```