# Ember js, get next item in model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to get the next item in model in ember.js?

something like:

```
var nextObjectAfterIdOne = this.store.getById(App.Model, '1').get('nextObject')
```

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424714/ember-link-to-next-object-in-model) but it seems a bit hacky, and the IDs in my application aren't necessarily sequential, and the items are ordered by a different attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's the good way to do it but at least it should work. Try to iterate over your list of item and once you find the current id, the next iteration will give you the next item.

```
var list = this.store.all(App.Model);
var id = 2;
var found = false;
var itemFound = undefined;
list.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if (found) {
        itemFound = item;
        return true;
    }
    if (item.get('id') == id) found = true;
});
```

This has not been tested but you can try it.